# SwiftUI function creating an Array instead of a Map in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

[image: Expected outcome in Firestore picture]

[image: current outcome in Firestore picture]

I am using below code in SwiftUI. For "readStatus", I am expecting to create map field and string values underneath, but instead I get an array with map field and string values with the below function.

What can I change within the "readStatus" portion of the code so that I see the expected outcome like in the photo within Firestore?

```
func createChannel() {  
        var data: [String: Any] = [
            "lastMessage": "A new channel created by \(currentusername)",
            "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()),
            "memberIds": uids,
            ]
            if let image = image {
                ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: image.aspectFittedToHeight(40), type: .channelprofile) { imageUrl in
                    data["imageUrl"] = imageUrl
                    data["readStatus"] = self.users.map({ [$0.id: "false"] })

                    Firestore.firestore().collection("channels")
                        .document(channelid)
                        .setData(data) { _ in
                            self.didCreatechannel = true
                }
            }
        }
```

Below works only for the current user mapping, but I am not sure how I can make it work for other users in the channel.

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
"readStatus":  [uid: "false"]
```